# Knime, relevant nodes for regression analysis ( statistical models)

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, knime

I need to use knime for regression analysis. I am a python user, I know knime as well but not in deep!
I usually use statsmodel in python for regression analysis and working on statistical models.

However for solving regression problem as a machine learning problem I use sklearn regression model. Each of these packages in python has its own benefit deepened on your task, and also different view of output which is really important to address the problem in the right way.
Here is my question, does knime present any special package for statistical model? If I plan to do a regression analysis which nodes are recommended?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Linear Regression Learner](https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.mine.regression.linear2.learner.LinReg2LearnerNodeFactory2) node under **Analytics** > **Mining** > **Linear/Polynomial Regression** in the node repository. Does that do what you need?